# Automatic deallocation on avr-gcc

Tags: c++, memory, embedded, avr-gcc

Programming a 8-bit AVR microcontroller I've came across a behavior that is
shown on this code:

```
  class classA
  {
      public:
          classA(Display *d) : _d(d) { _d->println("classA()", 0); }
          ~classA() { _d->println("~classA()", 1); }
          uint8_t array[200];
          Display *_d;
  };
  void useClassA(classA *a)
  {
      a->array[3] = 5;
  }
  void SomeClass::start()
  {
      SYSTEM_DISPLAY_FREE_RAM();
      debugMethod();
      _ui->lcd().println("after debugMethod", 3);
      SYSTEM_WAIT_DEBUG_BUTTON();
      SYSTEM_DISPLAY_FREE_RAM();
  }
  void SomeClass::debugMethod()
  {
      _ui->lcd().println("entered debugMethod", 3);
      SYSTEM_WAIT_DEBUG_BUTTON();
      SYSTEM_DISPLAY_FREE_RAM();

      _ui->lcd().println("before while", 3);
      SYSTEM_WAIT_DEBUG_BUTTON();
      volatile uint8_t i = 1;
      while (i != 0) 
      {
          classA cA(&_ui->lcd());
          SYSTEM_DISPLAY_FREE_RAM();
          cA.array[199] = i--;
          useClassA(&cA);
      }
      _ui->lcd().println("after while", 3);
      SYSTEM_WAIT_DEBUG_BUTTON();
      SYSTEM_DISPLAY_FREE_RAM();
  }
```

SYSTEM_DISPLAY_FREE_RAM() calculates available RAM as described in
http://jeelabs.org/2011/05/22/atmega-memory-use/.
When execution reaches SomeClass::start() I got the following output:

```
  Free Ram: 2677
  entered debugMethod
  Free Ram: 2458
  before while
  classA()
  Free Ram: 2458
  ~classA()
  after while
  Free Ram: 2458
  after debugMethod
  Free Ram: 2677
```

Despite `classA` object is created and destructed inside the `while`, the
memory seems to be allocated at the begging of `debugMethod()`, and remains
until the method ends. I expected memory to be allocated only inside of the
while, thus having a sigle print with `Free Ram: 2458`.

Any explanations of what is going on?

Is there a way to force the allocation to happen inside the `while`, without
using `new` keyword?

Compiler used: avr-gcc (WinAVR 20100110) 4.3.3

Comment: Did you compile with optimization? It might be the compiler moved the stack allocation to the beginning of debugMethod() as an optimization.

Comment: @Antti: yes, I compiled with `-O1`. I'll test with `-O0`.

Comment: @Antti: the same behavior happens with `-O0`, so its not because optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the stack frame for the whole function is allocated at the start of the function.
You can try the gcc argument `--param  min-pretend-dynamic-size=100` 
which will try to dynamically allocate and deallocate stack for objects over 100 bytes [1].

gcc can show you the assembly code with the `-S` switch, look at that to see under the hood on what's going on, and whether the --param  min-pretend-dynamic-size had any effect on your platform and function.

Another solution in your case would be to move the body of your while() loop into a new function, as that would create/destroy the stack frame containing the classA object.

[1] gcc docs:

**min-pretend-dynamic-size**

> Force any automatic object whose size in bytes is equal to or greater
>   than the specified value to be allocated dynamically, as if their size
>   wasn't known to compile time. This enables their storage to be
>   released at the end of the block containing them, reducing total stack
>   usage if multiple functions with heavy stack use are inlined into a
>   single function. It won't have any effect on objects that are suitable
>   for allocation to registers (i.e., that are sufficiently small and
>   that don't have their address taken), nor on objects allocated in the
>   outermost block of a function. The default, zero, causes objects whose
>   sizes are known at compile time to have storage allocated at function
>   entry.

Comment: The idea of param `min-pretend-dynamic-size` is very good, but unfortunatelly it is not accepted on this compiler: || avr-gcc -c -mmcu=atmega1281 -I. -x c++ -g -DF_CPU=14745600UL -O1 -fshort-enums -Wall --param min-pretend-dynamic-size=100 -IV0x05 -IV0x05/include -Ilib -MMD -MP -MF .dep/ADC3.o.d ADC3.cpp -o obj/Debug/ADC3.o 
|| cc1plus.exe: error: invalid parameter 'min-pretend-dynamic-size'

Comment: Yes, it seems that option was only available in some older gcc versions, I can't find anything similar in gcc 4.x and newer, though you could try `-fconserve-stack`

Comment: I've tried, and the compiler rejected this one too. Checking with `g++ -Q -O1 --help=optimizers` shows line `  -fconserve-stack              [disabled]` - same results for -O2, -O3 and -Os. Please let me know if you have more ideas. Thanks for your help!